# Can I repair Ubuntu after an interrupted upgrade?

Tags: boot, upgrade

I was in the middle of upgrading from 16.10 to 17.04. Eventually, during installing the upgrades, the OS sort of froze, but the mouse pointer and keyboard still worked (caps lock for example could still turn on/off) which I found weird. Since I couldn't do anything, I suspected something was wrong so I shut it off. When I turned it back on, it went through the usual boot phase. The cursor appeared for a second and then the "clearing orhpaned inode" screen looped over 10 times before the boot loader showed up and remained on the screen.

Can I repair Ubuntu somehow? I only have a 16.04 Live CD. I'm using Remix OS right now which is installed in the root directory. Or do I have to just reinstall?

Comment: What do you mean by the OS freezing? Did the windows just ignore your input? Did you try switching to tty1?

Comment: @rplaughlin Nothing worked at all including keyboard shortcuts, I couldn't access the terminal or anything. My laptop speakers are muted by default, so I unplugged my headphones to see if the volume icon icon would change but it didn't. Thankfully I was able to fix it, so I'll update it.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Glad to hear you fixed it. How did you fix it, may I ask? Could you write an answer for anyone else who might have the same problem?

Comment: @rplaughlin No problem. So am I, for a moment I thought I'd ultimately have to reinstall which I didn't look forward to doing. I wish I could go over how I fixed it but it took over a dozen steps through trial and error. I gave the starting point to what got me on the right track, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it. Going into recovery mode and repairing the broken packages (to some extent) started me off on the right track. That didn't solve *everything* initially, though. A lot of things were all screwed up in different areas, I had missing packages and altered settings, so it took awhile for me to get everything back to normal, but I have a fully upgraded 17.04 now.

While I don't have a step-by-step on how to fix it (I should have recorded the process), for anyone suffering similar problems, just go into recovery mode -- in the GRUB menu -- and press "repair broken packages". That may not solve everything or it might, but if it doesn't just let me know and I'll try to guide you through it if I can.

Comment: You should accept your answer so people can more easily see that it can be fixed.

Comment: @rplaughlin I haven't been able to and still can't do it yet. I have to wait 2 hours to accept my own answer according to the system in place.

Comment: I had a similar problem (interrupted update, then wlan not working, drm interface not set, etc.), and going through the "repair broken packages" GRUB option seems to have worked.